# Count the number of file descriptors opened by a process with lsof

Tags: process, administration, lsof

I need to check the number of file descriptors which are open by a Java process. The output of lsof  is almost 40000 lines long. Here's just the beginning:

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
java    12003 jboss  cwd       DIR              253,7      4096  1835012 /obcdn/Jboss/bin
java    12003 jboss  rtd       DIR              253,0      4096        2 /
java    12003 jboss  txt       REG              253,7      7336  2621459 /obcdn/java1.8/bin/java
java    12003 jboss  mem       REG              253,2    111080   171382 /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
java    12003 jboss  mem       REG              253,2     27776   133531 /usr/lib64/libnss_dns-2.17.so
java    12003 jboss  mem       REG              253,7    278078  1966631 /obcdn/Jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/yaml/snakeyaml/main/snakeyaml-1.15.0.redhat-1.jar
java    12003 jboss  mem       REG              253,7    360979  1835896 /obcdn/Jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/james/mime4j/main/apache-mime4j-0.6.0.redhat-5.jar
java    12003 jboss  mem       REG              253,7     32957  1835471 /obcdn/Jboss/modules/system/layers/base/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/main/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.5.4.redhat-1.jar
java    12003 jboss  mem       REG              253,7     28742  1835469 /obcdn/Jboss/modules/system/layers/base/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/main/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.5.4.redhat-1.jar
java    12003 jboss  mem       REG              253,7     16843  1835470 /obcdn/Jboss/modules/system/layers/base/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider
```

So it appears that the process is being using almost 40000 file descriptors, that seems a bit too much, also what I'm worried about is that an ulimit -a shows this maximum number of open files

```
open files                      (-n) 40000
```

Just to confirm my analysis: is each line of the lsof output actually a FD opened, or should I grep the output somehow to have the correct count ?
Thanks

Comment: You can also do `ls  /proc/$PID/fd/|wc -l` where PID is the process id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mem` aren't FDs, they're from `mmap()`.  So I would `grep -v " mem "` to be sure.  `cwd`, `rtd`, and `txt` are not FDs either, but there should be exactly one of each, so they won't have a very significant effect on your numbers.